# bootstrap checkbox button did not triggered in react

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I want to re-write https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons in `react`. Kindly review https://codepen.io/gamesover/pen/MoExWo?editors=1111 . There are two issues

1. Clicking `checkbox1`, `handleChange` is not triggered
2. Given `checkbox1` initial status is `on`, click the `checkbox1`, its status becomes `off`. However, the background color is still dark, you have to click somewhere else to make the button background color become light(off status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in reference to your codepen example.

The background color is depending on the 'active' class. In case of changing the checked status the active class is not getting change I guess.
I have created a simple github [repository](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-bootstrap-checkbox) with react setup. And is working as expected. Please check this once and let me know if this solves your issue.

Attaching a screenshot of console message that you wanted to print.

[image] Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your example. It looks there are some issues with my local git repository. I tested yours, all Good! Thank you again to prove I am wrong :)

Comment: No problem..glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example locally with a react setup and the console prints the message of handleChange.However, in codepen its not getting printed probably a codepen issue. Have you tried this on a local react setup? If not please do check once probably a codepen issue.

Comment: Yes, it did not work locally so I tested in codepen then. You may refer to `https://github.com/gamesover/cryptocurrency_trend` and change file `Trend.jsx` with 
`
<canvas ref="trend_chart"/>
        <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label className="btn btn-primary">
`
then function `toggleBTC` never be triggered. I am not sure whether it is related to `https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1587`

Comment: I have added a new answer with your codepen example. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/15‌​87 link is not working.